# While Loop inside Thread not working?

Tags: android, multithreading, while-loop

I have a very simple UI and i need to constantly run a check process, so I am trying to use a Thread with a while loop.
When I run the loop with nothing but a Thread.sleep(1000) command, it works fine, but as soon as I put in a display.setText(), the program runs for a second on the emulator then quits. I cannot even see the error message since it exits so fast.

I then took the display.setText() command outside the thread and just put it directly inside onCreate, and it works fine (so there is no problem with the actual command).

here is my code, and help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    on=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bon);
    off=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boff);
    display=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdisplay);
    display2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdisplay2);
    display3=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdisplay3);
    stopper=(Button) findViewById(R.id.stops);


    stopper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(boo=true)
            {
                boo=false;
                display3.setText("System Off");
            }
            else{
                boo=true;
            }
            }
    });





    Thread x = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (boo) {
                 display3.setText("System On");

                try {
                    // do something here
                    //display3.setText("System On");

                    Log.d(TAG, "local Thread sleeping");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "local Thread error", e);
                }

            }
        }
    };


    display3.setText("System On");
    display3.setText("System On");


    x.start();
}
```

Comment: the code relating to the thread would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! If you find an answer helpful, you can vote it up! If you feel that someone has adequately answered your question, click the check-mark next to the answer to accept it.

Comment: @AlanMoore, code added with original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't update the UI from a non-UI thread. Use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). Something like this could work:

```
// inside onCreate:
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        display3.setText("System On");
    }
};

Thread x = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        while (boo) {
            handler.invokeLater(updater);

            try {
                // do something here
                //display3.setText("System On");

                Log.d(TAG, "local Thread sleeping");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "local Thread error", e);
            }

        }
    }
};
```

You could also avoid a Handler for this simple case and just use

```
        while (boo) {
            runOnUiThread(updater);
            // ...
```

Alternatively, you could use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead of your own Thread class and override the `onProgressUpdate` method.

Comment: @user947659 I added a link to the Handler docs as well as some sample code.

Comment: Before I tried your solution, I set display.setText command inside the thread, just like in my code, but I just removed while loop. Can you please tell me why it works without a while loop? It is still modifying the UI from a non-UI thread.

Comment: You're not supposed to modify a UI from anythinh other than the UI thread; it may sometimes work, but this is down to luck, and should never be relied on.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% certain, but I think it is a case of not being able to modify UI controls from a thread that did not create them?

Answer (score 0):

When you are not in your UI thread, instead of `display3.setText("test")` use:

```
display3.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        display3.setText("test");
    {
});
```

Comment: You don't need to declare display3 as final if it is an instance variable.

Comment: But he declared 'display3' in a method.

Comment: He _initialized_ it in a method. I don't see a declaration `TextView display3` in his code.

Answer (score 0):

You should encapsulate this code in an AsyncTask instead. Like so:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  private Activity activity;
  MyTask(Activity activity){
    this.activity = activity;
  }  

  protected Long doInBackground() {
    while (true){
      activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
          display3.setText("System On");
        }
      });
      try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      }catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "local Thread error", e);
      }
   }  
}
```

Then just launch the task from your onCreate method.

Answer (score -1):

In non-UI thread,you can't update UI.In new Thread,you can use some methods to notice to update UI.

1. use Handler
2. use AsyncTask
3. use LocalBroadcast
4. if the process is the observer pattern,can use RxJava